# Merging columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am merging two columns in pandas but getting a problem with "None".

my df:

```
id    name1    name2
1     sam      None
2     None     slic
3     brm      dres
```

I am using the concatenation method to combine name1 and name2

```
df['New']   df['name1] + df['name2']
```

but when i use this then all the values with None neglected... I don't know why.  This is my output looks in the end

```
id    name1    name2     New 
3     brm      dres      brmdres
```

but i need this:

```
id    name1    name2       New
1     sam      None        sam
2     None     slic        slic
3     brm      dres        brmdres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a complete answer in the case where you only need to sum specific columns in the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name1': ['sam', None, 'brm'],
                   'name2': [None, 'slic', 'dres'],
                   'name3': ['sam2', 'slic2', 'dres2']})

df['new'] = df['name1'].fillna('') + df['name2'].fillna('')
```

Just to explain what is happening: the fillna('') is replacing the None's with an empty string '' in a copy of the column. This means you are actually adding 'sam' to the empty string '' which gives you 'sam' again.

Comment: I just updated my answer so I'm hoping it's a bit clearer, let me know which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try filter with `replace` if the `None` is `string` `type`, if not do `fillna('')`

```
df.filter(like='name').replace('None','').sum(1)
0        sam
1       slic
2    brmdres
dtype: object
```

Comment: the df is imaginary... if i need to sum only specific columns?

Comment: @s_khan92 list_of_col= ['name1','name2'];df[list_of_col].replace('None','').sum(1)

Comment: It changed all values to 0.0

Comment: @s_khan92 can you do df.head()to_dict()  show us your data ? I do not think the sample data address the real problem

Comment: `{'URL': {12: 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/omd_image_analyser_koenig/Feier/feierabend_post_img_13.jpg',
  21: 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/omd_image_analyser_koenig/Feier/feierabend_post_img_22.jpg',
  27: 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/omd_image_analyser_koenig/Feier/feierabend_post_img_28.jpg'},
 'Wein': {12: 'Wein', 21: 'Wein', 27: 'Wein'},
 'Beer': {12: nan, 21: nan, 27: nan}}`

Comment: Need to combine wein and beer

Comment: @s_khan92 that is look like numeric value not string

Answer (score 0):

A solution I like:

```
df['new'] = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
```